# primary stress of "flying doctor" and "flying officer"

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

Do you know why the primary stress falls on the "doctor" of "flying doctor" but on the first component of "flying officer"?

In case you don't know what "flying doctor" and "flying officer" refer to, here are the definitions:

> flying doctor: ​(especially in Australia) a doctor who travels in an aircraft to visit patients who live far from a town
>
> flying officer: an officer of fairly low rank in the British air force

Comment: A flying doctor is a doctor who happens to visit patients by air. All RAF officers (potentially) fly, so _flying_ is not a distinctive characteristic of this particular rank.

Comment: My school geography teacher, who was Flight Lieutenant Phillips on cadet day each week, was an RAF reserve officer, and he never flew, in the sense of piloting planes. He had been a meteorologist in WW2, and that is a ground duty.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, a friend of mine is married to a former RAF officer who didn't fly, which is why I said 'potentially'. I meant that a Flying Officer isn't the only rank who flies!

Answer (score 1):

Good question. To be honest, there isn't a really a "rule" that says where the emphasis should be placed in a colligation, and this can differ between BrE, AmE, and AuE, as well as between regional accents of all these places. I have noted, for example, that Americans tend to place emphasis on the first name of "*Robin* Hood" - particularly the first syllable - whereas British people emphasise the surname "Robin *Hood*".

As a general rule of thumb, we tend to emphasise the most "important" word in any sentence. For example, if someone said "I've got a red car", you might respond "I have a *blue* car" with emphasis on the colour because the whole point of your statement is that you have a different colour car. On the other hand, if your response was that you had a different vehicle but the same colour, your emphasis might be in a different place - "I have a red *bike*".

I don't think that "flying *doctor*" is so unusual - the emphasis on the second word is the same as I would expect in "flying ant", or "flying car". Lots of things fly, so the noteworthy thing is that he is a doctor.

"*Flying* officer" is different. It is because he is an officer *of* flying, rather than an officer that flies. Think of "*driving* instructor" - he is an instructor of driving, rather than an instructor that drives. In fact, lots of job titles have emphasis on the first word - for example "*pop* singer", "*office* worker", or "*window* cleaner".

Comment: Why does the stress fall on the first component of "Flying Squad"? I doubt that the Flying Squad necessarily flies.

Comment: Astralbee - Flying Officer (abbr. F/O or Fg Off), is an RAF and Commonwealth air force _rank_ - Pilot Officer, Flying Officer, Flight Lieutenant,  and Squadron Leader are the equivalents of army 2/Lt, 1/Lt, Captain, and Major respectively.

Comment: @Apollyon Because they are not a 'squad of flying' - they are a squad that flies, metaphorically.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes it is a rank, or title. 'Arch Bishop' is a title as well, but the emphasis is on the second word. It isn't the fact that it is a title that makes it so, which is why I haven't dwelled on that in my answer.

Comment: @Astralbee - I was about to berate you for "Arch Bishop", but I see the two-word variant of "Archbishop" is still in use by some of the faithful. Dear Justin Welby, though, calls himself "Archbishop" on his Facebook page.